# Exclude unlink if string contains X

Tags: php, file-get-contents, strpos, unlink

I have a question relating to some file deletions. Lets start with the code

```
$dir = "./reporting/live-metrics/";
foreach (glob($dir."*") as $file) {
$live = file_get_contents($file);
if (strpos($live, 'CORO') !== false) {
}
if (filemtime($file) < time() - 3 * 60) {
    $exclude[] = $live;
    unlink($file);
    }
}
```

I am pretty sure my use of file_get_contents and strpos is incorrect. My attempt is that multiple files are created in live-metrics and the only constant is on line 2 of the file (either CORO or EMER). I am attempting to exclude any file that contains CORO within the file while deleting any other file after 3 minutes modified time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the two conditions

```
if (strpos($live, 'CORO') === false && filemtime($file) < time() - 3 * 60) {
    $exclude[] = $live;
    unlink($file);
}
```

You could also write:

```
if (strpos($live, 'CORO') !== false {
    continue;
}
```

`continue` skips the rest of the loop body and goes to the next iteration.

Comment: I tried your combination but it does not seem to delete the files anymore at all. I think the issue may be with the file_get_contents.

Comment: I left out the `()` after `time`.